# How can I do this operation in C programming?

Tags: c

I have a number: for example, 2136521. I am using this formula 213 (1st, 2nd and 3rd digits of the number) — adding these digits (2+1+3), then calculating the remainder from division by 7 (which is 6), and writing that digit instead of the three digits.
I mean:

```
 2136521=
 ( 1-2-3.term of number) = 213((2+1+3)%7=6)
 ( 2-3-4.term of number) = 136((1+3+6)%7=3)
 ( 3-4-5.term of number) = 365((3+6+5)%7=0)
 ( 4-5-6.term of number) = 652((6+5+2)%7=6)
 ( 5-6-7.term of number) = 521((5+2+1)%7=1)
```

The result of this operation is 63061. How can I do this operation in C programming?

Comment: If you make an attempt to code anything, then you will get more help because you will end up asking a more specific question. I can clearly see what you are trying to do but you need to try first. Just take it one step at a time.

Comment: The right question would be: How can i do this operation. Stop.

Comment: Treat the number as a string of digits — format it with `sprintf()`. for example, or read it as a string rather than as a number (using `scanf()` or `fgets()` or whatever).  Then coding it is relatively simple.  Check that the number is at least 100; then you can work with three digits at a time very easily, forming either a string or a number as you choose.  I'd probably format into a string, remembering to null terminate it, and then, if necessary, use `strtol()` or `sscanf()` to convert it back to a number.  What is the largest number you have to work with?

Comment: Can I help? You have suddenly removed the accepted of the answer? reason?

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin function to do that for you. You have to write a function which would keep track of the last digit and the sum of the last 3 digits. Then you can get the new digit sum by doing this `new_dig_sum = old_dig_sum - old_dig + new_dig`. To get the digits you can do the modulo operation. (For positive numbers `x`, `x%10` gives the last digit).